# Error on control cast - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

Right now, I'm trying to refactor my c# code and I need some advices :)
Sorry if there are any grammar/spelling mistakes, english is not my native language

Many times in my code I change text of TableCells, TextBox, Label, etc ... with a little test (Always the same test on a DateTime). 
So I figured out it would be great the refactor all of these into a single generic method. But I have some problems with it.

Here's my code for the method :

```
 private void testDateTimeNonValideIntoControls<T>((DateTime date, ref Control control)
 {
        string convertedDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label))
        {
            if (convertedDate != "01/01/0001") 
                ((Label)control).Text = convertedDate; 
            else
                ((Label)control).Text = " --- "; 
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell))
        {
            if (convertedDate != "01/01/0001") 
                ((TableCell)control).Text = convertedDate; 
            else
                ((TableCell)control).Text = " --- "; 
        }

        [...]

    }
```

I'm not used to generic method/class but I think there is something wrong in that method.

Still, when I call it :

testDateTimeNonValideIntoControls((DateTime date, ref Control control)

```
testDateTimeNonValideIntoControls<Label>(date1st, ref (Control)LabelValueDatePremContrat);
```

I have an error on the 'control' cast. "A ref or out argument must be assignable variable"
So I tried to do something like

```
ref (Control)(ref LabelValueDD)
```

But nope, again.

Anyone can give me some help on this one ? I would like to be able to use generic methods :) !

Comment: Hi why are you using ref with control? 
private void testDateTimeNonValideIntoControls<T>((DateTime date, ref Control control)
as control is already reference type so we don't need this. Just remove ref with control in function definition

Comment: Last time I tried it didnt work :o ! But now it does :D ! Thanks Numan Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, that's not making the most of generics, and could be written without them, so something like:

```
private void testDateTimeNonValideIntoControls(DateTime date, Control control)
{
    string convertedDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    if (string.Equals(convertedDate, "01/01/0001"))
    {
        convertedDate = " --- "; 
    }

    var lbl = control as Label;
    if (lbl != null)
    {
        lbl.Text = convertedDate;
    }
    else
    {
        var td = control as TableCell;
        if (td != null)
        {
            td.Text = convertedDate;
        }

        // [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the method header to

```
private void testDateTimeNonValideIntoControls<T>(DateTime date,Control control)
```

(removed ref next to 'control')

Also,

I'll follow Rownland's answer. I forgot about the 'as' word

Thanks